# Accurately calculate days between two dates (including time)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm working on a front-end app, and was trying to calculate number of days between two dates, and the more I read on proper/accurate way of working out the days between two dates, the more I got confused.

So I thought, I shall post another question on here to finally shed some light on this confusion.

Also I was trying to workout when it would be safest to do the calculation; is it when I get the raw UTC date I get from the backend below, after they're converted to Locale date and time? What I mean by this, would it be better to get the diff between UTC dates or diff between Locale date and time?

### Here are UTC dates:

```
UTC Date 1:  2014-11-30T15:41:51.012+0000
UTC Date 2:  2014-01-09T02:56:36.000+0000
```

### Here are Locale dates (On Windows; this will be diff format on Linux):

```
Locale Date 1:  11/30/2014, 3:41:51 PM
Locale Date 2:  1/9/2014, 2:56:36 AM
```

So my questions are, which one of those would give accurate daysBetweenDates, UTC or Locale? Also how is this calculated, a JavaScript function snippet or demo would help me and others.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really got the question, but UTC obviously has 3 digits after comma resolution, while second "locale" examples has only integer seconds resolution. Additionally, UTC has information about time zone.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the results? What did you get? JavaScript stores dates in UTC, how a user will see a date depends on the toString method used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it with pure JS:

```
var Date1 = new Date('2014-11-30T15:41:51.012+0000'.substr(0,10)).getTime();
var Date2 = new Date('2014-01-09T02:56:36.000+0000'.substr(0,10)).getTime();
var Diff = Math.floor(Math.max(Date1,Date2)-Math.min(Date1,Date2))/1000/60/60/24;
```

Comment: UTC or Locale version? and can you explain why would it give an accurate date and time diff in days? Also this return NaN

Comment: I don't think it matters but UTC would probably be a better preference. Basically you can think of Date1 and Date2 as being the amount of milliseconds since January 1 1970. By subtracting the initial date from the later date, you end up with the amount of milliseconds in time difference between the two dates. By converting this value to days and flooring the value, you end up with an accurate result.

Comment: I just did this:         
`console.log('Diff UTC: ', Math.floor(('2014-11-30T16:27:16.059+0000'-'2014-01-09T02:56:36.000+0000')/1000/60/60/24));` and got `NaN`

Comment: Also, why are we not taking times into consideration, since that would make a difference over time when calculating diff in dates?

Comment: I removed them because I didn't think you needed that extra information. The entire format you've specified isn't directly compatible with JS so I did a quick implementation.

Comment: @Simple-Solution I edited my answer again so you can use it without having to worry about the order of Date1 and Date2 but you may have to do some string manipulation to get it translated and working exactly how you want it. The first two lines simply create the date objects and hold the timestamp. The last line calculates the difference in days between them.

Comment: What is the diff between `var Diff = Math.floor(Math.abs(Date1-Date2))/ONE_DAY;` and `var Diff = Math.floor(Math.max(Date1,Date2)-Math.min(Date1,Date2))/1000/60/60/24;`?

Comment: @Simple-Solution ONE_DAY isn't supported by native JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was diff between `Math.abs() and Math.max()-Math.min()`, but thanks for the ONE_DAY!

Comment: @Simple-Solution I completely forgot `Math.abs` existed. That should work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd use Moment.js

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```
var a = moment('2014-11-30T15:41:51.012+0000');
var b = moment('2014-11-30T15:41:51.012+0000');
var dayDiff = a.diff(b, 'days');
```

You could do it natively, but this does it for you, it's lightweight, it'll handle all your locale woes and chances are you're going to want other date manipulation elsewhere that you can also use it for

Comment: @J Tolley - can you provide an example without using any library please.

Comment: Well no, sorry. The whole point of my answer is I'm suggesting you use a library and save yourself the headache. I'm sure there'll be another answer with sample code if you're desperate to do it natively.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. Also how accurate is your approach, not sure how this function does in the background, can you explain what it does in the background please.